# No element found with ID 'reviews.tab'

Tags: product, exception, view

I'm facing this issue.

> Exception #0 (OutOfBoundsException): No element found with ID 'reviews.tab'.

Anyone have an idea about this one?

```
1 exception(s):
```

Exception #0 (OutOfBoundsException): No element found with ID 'reviews.tab'.

Exception #0 (OutOfBoundsException): No element found with ID 'reviews.tab'.

```
#1 Magento\Framework\Data\Structure->getAttribute('reviews.tab', 'display') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:511]
#2 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->displayElement('reviews.tab') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:487]
#3 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('reviews.tab') called at [app/code/MGS/Protabs/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details.phtml:67]
#4 include('/var/www/html/su...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description#0000000007a937c9000000005b3f1be4#, '/var/www/html/su...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:270]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/su...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:300]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:667]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('product.info.det...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:533]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('product.info.det...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('product.info.det...', true) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:507]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('product.info.det...') called at [app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/detail_layout.phtml:150]
#13 include('/var/www/html/su...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor#0000000007a937d1000000005b3f1be4#, '/var/www/html/su...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:270]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/su...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:300]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:667]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('product.detail.i...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:533]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('product.detail.i...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('product.detail.i...', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#27 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#36 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:954]
#39 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#40 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#41 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#42 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', array(), array(array('layout-model-cac...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:39]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:257]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000007a93030000000005b3f1be4#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:170]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000007a93030000000005b3f1be4#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#46 MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000007a93030000000005b3f1be4#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#47 MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000007a93030000000005b3f1be4#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#48 MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000007a93030000000005b3f1be4#), array(array('result-messages', 'result-builtin-c...', 'result-varnish-c...'))) called at [generated/code/MGS/Mpanel/Block/Framework/Page/Interceptor.php:39]
#49 MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#0000000007a93030000000005b3f1be4#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:140]
#50 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:257]
#51 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#0000000007a93032000000005b3f1be4#) called at [index.php:39]
```

Comment: where showed this error ?? i means products page ??

Comment: Search all your XML files for reviews.tab - what do you find?

Comment: I see this Exception when I click on a single product.

Comment: This is my block: <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review" name="reviews.tab" template="MGS_Amp::Magento_Review/review.phtml">

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be help you

By just adding lines in below file in `mymodule_index_index.xml` files page node I Add `layout=1column` and the problem is solved.

Comment: Can you clarify your point please?

Comment: Please open the your xml file for related to review tab...

Comment: You create any custom module for review tab???

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: Your create any new Or rewrite xml files for related for review tab???

Comment: No, Magento + theme...

Answer (score 0):

I fix this by disabling the module loll!